# How to access common values from two or more columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I need to find the number of common values in a column wrt another column.

For example:
There are two columns `X` , `Y`.

| X: | a | b | c | a | d | a | b | b | a | a |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Y: | NaN | 2 | 4 | Nan | NaN | 6 | 4 | NaN | 5 | 4 |

So how do I **group values** like **NaN** wrt **a,b,c,d.**

For example,

`a` has `2 NaN` values.

`b` has `1 NaN` values.

Comment: are `X` and `Y` rows or columns :). Should `X` and `Y` be transposed from rows to columns (long instead of wide)? Currnetly, X and Y are rows, but you say "columns" in your question. Kindly clarify. Thank you.

Comment: i suspect your actual df doesn't have duplicate column headings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my comment, I have transposed your dataframe with `df.set_index(0).T` to get the following starting point.

```
In[1]: 
0   X    Y
1   a  NaN
2   b    2
3   c    4
4   a  NaN
5   d  NaN
6   a    6
7   b    4
8   b  NaN
9   a    5
10  a    4
```

From there, you can filter for null values with `.isnull()`. Then, you can use `.groupby('X').size()` to return the count of null values per group:

```
df[df['Y'].isnull()].groupby('X').size()

X
a    2
b    1
d    1
dtype: int64
```

Or, you could use `value_counts()` to achieve the same thing:

```
df[df['Y'].isnull()]['X'].value_counts()
```

Comment: thanks David! Do I need to create a duplicate dataframe for only those two columns?

Comment: @Vignesh you can create a duplicate dataframe with `df1 = df.copy()` and then use `df1` from there OR you can overwrite the existing dataframe by just using `df = ..` Both should work.